# Why does my BeanManager does not find my bean?

Tags: dependency-injection, jboss7.x, javabeans

I just joined a Java project in which we use org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl as our BeanManager.
We have a method that created the beans from its class when required:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Qualifier... qualifiers) {
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(clazz, qualifiers); //problem here
        logger.debug("found {} instances for {}", beans.size(), clazz);

        Bean<?> bean = (Bean<?>) beans.iterator().next();

        CreationalContext<?> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        return clazz.cast(beanManager.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx));
    }
```

It works for all other developers, but not for me.  On the first line, the result is an EmptyImmutableSetm while for the other DEVs the bean is found.
Is there any problem with my project setup? My colleagues tried to help me out on that but we got nowhere. 
Where does the beanManager look for the beans? Is there maybe a classpath problem?

Comment: Is this a Java EE project or a Java SE project?

Comment: Java EE. I deleted the projects from Eclipse and reimported them. It is working. sorry for the late reply

Comment: Excellent. Just as an FYI you really shouldn't be using a BeanManager implementation. Use the `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager` instead.